# How to prevent bots from manipulating view amounts

Tags: node.js, security, express, bots

I am creating a media site where people can upload and view videos and other content, currently I have a very rudimentary system for updating the views where each request for the media I increment the view count by one. Well, it only took a day before someone set up a bot to start spamming the endpoints of his videos.

What's a good approach to preventing this? I don't really want to ban IPs, I'd prefer to have 3-5 seconds between requests to consider the request legitimate, but I've thought about this without any really great ideas, what would you suggest?

Comment: do you want to increment the views by 1 when the same ip views it too?

Comment: You mean the same ip views the video they uploaded? That's fine with me, I found a solution in node-ddos module that basically prevents rapid spamming

Answer (score 1):

> In real life, when you don't
>   like someone and don't want to talk to him, what do you do? You get
>   away from him. *How do you do that?* Your brain has stored his face and previous memories about him so that it
>   knows what to do in case of *confrontation*..

It is the same with computers, you need to store the IPs to the *database* when the ip acts unusual.

***How do we achieve it***?

When a request is made more than once in a very short period of time your server needs to store to it to its *blacklist* database. Same with how *jails* are in real life. You let it go whenever **you** want to. Your server also needs to know what action to take when the criminal sends a request *again*.

***What is the action to take?***

We drop the *requests* made by the criminal.

***How to release the criminal after a short period of time?***

Your server needs to keep track of time, in your ***blacklist*** notebook (database) you need to store the date when the criminal was put to the jail, and so the server knows when to automatically *release* him.

***What action to take by the server to release the criminal?***

You need to have level of crimes. The first time it is `level1`, so the criminal's requests will be dropped by 10 seconds each time i.e.

**`level2`** `=>`
You are dropping the *requests* for even longer period of times.

**`level3`** `=>`
You are dropping the *requests* for good.

***For you to understand better, here is an example of some code from the blacklist..***

`IP=75.64.123.34; Date=Mon-Aug-13/2017-08-07; level=1`

***Databases***

You need to *create jails*, depending on the database you are using,

Let's say you have *mySQL*, you are going to need to create a *table* which is only used for *blacklisted IPs* E.g. If you're using *mongoDB*, you should create a new schema just for this ***task***.

***With each request, the server must check the blacklisted IPS***

Yes, you heard it right, when a client makes a request, the server needs pull out that notebook and see if the client's IP is in there, if it is not, it must let him *pass*.

***Will it slow down the server?***

Yes it will, maybe not too much depending on your ***server's power***. You also need to avoid extra code and make the process as simple as possible. This way you can drop down the slow ratio to *milliseconds*.

Hope you like it!